# Angular material icons are not visible after filling the values

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular6

I am using this html example to have some folders created:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="8" rowHeight="100px" fxFlex>

  <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let element of fileElements" class=file-or-folder>
    <span [matMenuTriggerFor]="rootMenu" 
          [matMenuTriggerData]="{element: element}" 
          #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger">
    </span>
    <div  fxLayout="column" 
          fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" 
          (click)="navigate(element)" 
          (contextmenu)="openMenu($event, menuTrigger)">

      <mat-icon color="primary" 
                class="file-or-folder-icon pointer" 
                *ngIf="element.isFolder">
        folder
      </mat-icon>
      <mat-icon color="primary" 
                class="file-or-folder-icon pointer" 
                *ngIf="!element.isFolder">
        insert_drive_file
      </mat-icon>

      <span>{{element.name}}</span>
    </div>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

And in order to fill them I have a list of objects that I am giving values after calling an http get request.

My actual component code is:

```
 .subscribe((data:any) => {
      this.fileElements = data;
  }, 
  error => console.log(error),
  () => { console.log(Completed fetching), 
        this.fileElements.forEach(....);
   }
 }
```

And I expect to see for each element a folder in the browser. I have the above code inside the ngOnInit() method. My guess is that because it is asynchronous when it is in the completed section maybe the list in not filled yet. Any ideas on how can I have them in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing same issue when used *ngIf with mat-icon.

Try `display` property instead *ngIf.

```
  <mat-icon color="primary" 
                class="file-or-folder-icon pointer" 
                [style.display]="element.isFolder ? 'block':'none'">
        folder
      </mat-icon>
```